# shell_exec in php works good for the default shells commands such as ls but is not working the same with hadoop commands

Tags: php, shell, hadoop

while using `shell_exec` in `php` for example

```
$make=shell_exec('ls');
echo $make;
```

it returns the results in our webpage but when we use `hadoop fs -ls` instead of ls it doesn't return anything does shell_exec works with hadoop shell commands
or is there any other way to do the same i also tried it using the commands in python scripts and then executing those scripts using `php's shell_exec` but still no good

Comment: Please reword you question so it can be better understood, put any code inside code blocks, and break into sentences/parts.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that the handoop executable is not in the path of current working directory or context.
Try to execute the command with full path instead. 
For example: 
instead of using command like: `shell_exec('hadoop fs -ls');`
**use** `shell_exec('/usr/bin/hadoop fs -ls');`

I don't know the exact location of handoop executable on your system. use mlocate utility to find the exact file location.